# Probality, car punctures during a jorney, exponential distribution - How to silve?

Tags: probability

*I have an interesting math problem which is the next:*

At cars, the length of journeys between two punctures is independent and exponentially distributed. The probability of not getting a puncture within 50,000 km 0.2.

**A) Within how many km do we get a puncture with a probability of 0.99?**

```
   I think it means the nexts:

   P(x<50000) = 1-P(x>50000) = 0.8 that I have punctures during this length of jorney
   
   Then
          lambda = 3.2188758248682⋅10−5**.

   P(x<?) = 0.99 -  The solution for this: 143067.655807339 Km
```

The equation that has been solved: $$1 - e^{- 3.2188758248682 \cdot 10^{-5} x} = 0.99$$

**B) What is the probability that we will get a maximum of 1 puncture during 100,000 km?**

**C) What is the smallest number of punctures when the probability is 0.99 on 1 million km?**

My questions:

**Is the calculation correct at A) ?
I have no idea at B) , C), could you help me?**

Thanks in advance for your advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for showing your work so far. That lets me know how to give clues for the rest.

(A) You solved the CDF to get $\lambda =  3.218876e-05,$ which gives
$P(X \le 50000) = 0.8,$ as required. In R:

```
lam = -log(.2)/50000; lam
[1] 3.218876e-05
pexp(50000, lam)
[1] 0.8
```

Then $q = 143067.7$ has $P(X \le q) = 0.99,$ as you say.

```
qexp(.99, lam)
[1] 143067.7
```

(B) Note that $\lambda$ above is the rate of punctures per (one) km.
Let $N$ be the number of punctures in 100,000 km. which has
$N \sim \mathsf{Pois}(100\,000 \lambda)$ and we seek $P(N \le 1) =0.168755.$

```
ppois(1, 100000*lam)
[1] 0.168755
```

(C) Now you need the rate for a million km. Use the 99th quantile
as you did in (A).

```
qpois(.99, 10^6*lam)
[1] 46
ppois(46, 10^6*lam)
[1] 0.9916014
ppois(45, 10^6*lam)
[1] 0.9872919
```

*Note:* In addition to being a problem about exponential and Poisson distributions, this also seems to be about keeping track of decimal points. Better check my computations and yours for that.